# Convert JSON array of strings to Java?

Tags: java, javascript, json, converters

I am trying to convert a JSON String array to Java which is given from this piece of javascript:

```
javaFunction(["a1", "a2"]); <--- This is called in javascript
```

In Java

```
public static void javaFunction(<What here?> jsonStringArray){  //<---- This is called in Java
    //Convert the JSON String array here to something i can iterate through,
    //For example:

    for(int index = 0; index < convertedArray.length; index++){
        System.out.println(convertedArray[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a Java API for JSON processing: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

Comment: Can you print your json array and show it so we could give you an exact answer ?

Comment: The JSON array is in the question first code line

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < jsonStringArray.length(); i++){
  list.add(jsonStringArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
  }
```

Comment: Okay.. but where does the .getString("name") come from? and what should I fill in at the javaFunction parameters.. for example should it be JSONArray jsonStringArray? String jsonStringArray?

Comment: In the java method, just send the json array that needs to be converted. And your json array should be in the key-value pair. So getString is taking the value for every key and adding it to the list.

Comment: Yes I know! But what type is jsonStringArray? public static void javaFunction(<WHAT HERE?????> jsonStringArray)

Comment: JSONArray dude. It is the type

public static void javaFunction(JSONArray jsonStringArray)

Comment: Ok, with that i get the following error message: Can't find method javaFunction(object)

Comment: Are you calling the java method from the javascript ? Can you show how you are calling ?

Comment: I show that in the question, the top code line, nothing more than that, when i pass some string and accept some string in java it finds the method. Indicating the method is called properly, but the object / JSONArray is the problem

Comment: Look, JavaScript is a client side side language and java is a server side language, it cannot communicate. However you can parse a JSONArray in a javascript simply by :

var arr = JSON.parse(jsonStringArray);

And then try alert(arr) to check the values

Comment: Solved it, look at the answer below.. Thanks for your help though! you had the right general idea direction with JSON.parse.. that gave me the idea to give the Array as a string. with JSON.Stringify. Also.. as a final note: "JavaScript is a client side language and java is a server side language, it cannot communicate" is just downright not true. I use it all the time, people use it all the time

Comment: Glad your issue got solved, when I said it can't communicate, I meant it is not recommended! Anyways cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this:

In the JavaScript:

```
javaFunction(JSON.Stringify(["a1", "a2"]));
```

In Java

```
public static void javaFunction(String jsonArrayString){
   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArrayString);
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
      list.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
   }
}
```

Comment: So you converted it into string format ? How did this solve the problem ?

Comment: Because now the java method expects a string and actually gets a string. so it won't give me errors exceptions and all that bad stuff

Answer (score 0):

Trim first and last bracket;

**i.e.** 
`jsonArrayString = jsonArrayString.subStr(1,jsonArrayString.length()-1);`

you will get "a1","a2","a3","a4"

Then use String's split function.

```
String[] convertedArray= jsonArrayString.split(",");
```